# Converting one string to a int in a list

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

I want to convert a str into an int in a list.  Example:

```
x = ['1', '24', 'M', 'technician', '85711']
```

I want just the first element `x[0]` to switch to an int:

```
x = [1, '24', 'M', 'technician', '85711']
```

Comment: `x[0] = int(x[0])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign to an index of the list:

```
>>> x = ['1', '24', 'M', 'technician', '85711']
>>> x[0] = int(x[0])
>>> x
[1, '24', 'M', 'technician', '85711']
>>>
```

This solution keeps the list object the same too:

```
>>> x = ['1', '24', 'M', 'technician', '85711']
>>> id(x)
35174000
>>> x[0] = int(x[0])
>>> id(x)
35174000
>>>
```

Comment: I guess I should have posted it as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc That's going to be the title of my autobiography if I ever write about answering questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc - I actually didn't see your comment until _after_ I posted.  But yes, your idea was the correct solution.  +1 on your comment. :)

Comment: I posted it several seconds before you did.  |=^/  Brb going to cry for a few hours

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Don't worry.  The most upvoted answers are usually the sort of FAQs to which one posts the answer as a comment (and those questions are upvoted too).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to convert just all digits to int in a mixed list , try it:

```
a = ['1', '24', 'M', 'technician', '85711']
b = map(lambda x: int(x) if str(x).isdigit() else x,a)
print b
```

output:

```
[1, 24, 'M', 'technician', 85711]
```

Comment: The OP said that he wants to convert just the first number (`x[0]`) into an integer.  Your solution will convert every number.

Comment: @iCodez you are right , I just wanted to help him that can convert all digits to int in a mixed list.